# Set custom and changing baseline to stem plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, stem

I'm triying to make a figure where the stem plot has the baseline on the data of `dataframe_3_merged['TOTAL']`.

```
import numpy as np
from eurostatapiclient import EurostatAPIClient
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
#Set versions and formats, so far only the ones used here are availeable and call client
VERSION = 'v2.1'
FORMAT = 'json'
LANGUAGE = 'en'
client = EurostatAPIClient(VERSION, FORMAT, LANGUAGE)



dataframe_3_query_total = 'ilc_peps01?precision=1&sex=T&geo=AT&geo=BE&geo=BG&geo=CH&geo=CY&geo=CZ&geo=DK&geo=EA19&geo=EE&geo=EL&geo=ES&geo=EU28&geo=FI&geo=FR&geo=HR&geo=HU&geo=IE&geo=IS&geo=IT&geo=LT&geo=LU&geo=LV&geo=ME&geo=MK&geo=MT&geo=NL&geo=NO&geo=PL&geo=PT&geo=RO&geo=RS&geo=SE&geo=SI&geo=SK&geo=TR&geo=UK&unit=PC&unitLabel=label&time=2018&age=TOTAL'
dataframe_3_query_urb = 'ilc_peps13?precision=1&deg_urb=DEG1&deg_urb=DEG2&deg_urb=DEG3&geo=AT&geo=BE&geo=BG&geo=CH&geo=CY&geo=CZ&geo=DE&geo=DK&geo=EA19&geo=EE&geo=EL&geo=ES&geo=EU28&geo=FI&geo=FR&geo=HR&geo=HU&geo=IE&geo=IS&geo=IT&geo=LT&geo=LU&geo=LV&geo=MK&geo=MT&geo=NL&geo=NO&geo=PL&geo=PT&geo=RO&geo=RS&geo=SE&geo=SI&geo=SK&geo=UK&unit=PC&unitLabel=label&time=2018'


dataframe_3_total = client.get_dataset(dataframe_3_query_total).to_dataframe().pivot(index = 'geo',columns = 'age',values = 'values')
dataframe_3_urb =client.get_dataset(dataframe_3_query_urb).to_dataframe().pivot(index = 'geo',columns = 'deg_urb',values = 'values')

dataframe_3_merged = dataframe_3_total.join(dataframe_3_urb).dropna()


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 4))
plt.ylim(0,51)

x = range(0,32,1)
stem_1 =plt.stem(x,dataframe_3_merged['DEG1'])
stem_2=plt.stem(x, dataframe_3_merged['DEG2'])
stem_3=plt.stem(x, dataframe_3_merged['DEG3'])
plt.setp(stem_2, color = 'r')
plt.setp(stem_3, color = 'g')

scatterplot= sns.scatterplot(x=dataframe_3_merged.index, #We draw the scatterplot and specify the arguments
                             y = dataframe_3_merged['TOTAL'],
                             ax=ax ,
                             s = 100 ,
                             legend = False,
                             marker="_",
                             color = 'b')
```

The goal is to have a plot similar to this image:
[image: 1]
I tried to use the list `dataframe_3_merged['TOTAL']` as the parameter in the bottom argument of plt.stem but I have this traceback: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace each stem plot by a scatter plot and a plot of vertical lines (`plt.vlines`). Setting the `zorder=0` ensures the lines are drawn behind the dots.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

names = ['hydrogen', 'helium', 'lithium', 'beryllium', 'boron', 'carbon', 'nitrogen', 'oxygen', 'fluorine', 'neon', 'sodium', 'magnesium', 'aluminium', 'silicon', 'phosphorus', 'sulphur', 'chlorine', 'argon', 'potassium', 'calcium', 'scandium', 'titanium', 'vanadium', 'chromium', 'manganese', 'iron', 'cobalt', 'nickel', 'copper', 'zinc', 'gallium', 'germanium', 'arsenic', 'selenium', 'bromine', 'krypton']

N = len(names)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Deg1': 35 + np.random.normal(size=N).cumsum(),
                   'Deg2': 25 + np.random.normal(size=N).cumsum(),
                   'Deg3': 15 + np.random.normal(size=N).cumsum()},
                  index=names)
df['Total'] = df.mean(axis=1)

for deg, color, label in zip(['Deg1', 'Deg2', 'Deg3'], ['tomato', 'orange', 'palegreen'],
                             ['label1', 'label2', 'label3']):
    plt.vlines(df.index, df[deg], df['Total'], lw=0.2, color='k', zorder=0)
    plt.scatter(df.index, df[deg], marker='o', color=color, label=label)
plt.scatter(df.index, df['Total'], marker='_', color='deepskyblue', s=100)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.ylim(0, 51)
plt.margins(x=0.02)
plt.legend(ncol=3, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.4), loc='upper center')
plt.grid(True, axis='y')
plt.tick_params(length=0)
for where in ['top', 'left', 'right']:
    plt.gca().spines[where].set_visible(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip it solved my problem in a easier way than the stem plot